# Twitter for iPad UI - How does it work?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, navigation

Twitter for iPad introduced a new way of browsing content. Does anyone have a guess of how these sliding panels are managed? Is it one big `UIScrollView` with a bunch of `UITableViews` in it? Or a bunch of `UIViewControllers` sliding on top of each other? Or something else? What's your bet?

Comment: My biggest question: is the horizontal scrolling a UIScrollView (inertia for free!) with a bunch of crazy code on top to implement the page stops and stacking? Or did Loren implement all of that behavior from scratch?

Comment: Could it be they use a modified UIPageControll to get the horizontal inertia?

Comment: @Janco: UIPageControl is just a UI element. It can't do anything by itself (except responding to right/left tap but you still need to connect it to a controller).

Answer (score 3):

I think the trick here isn't in the view types used, but rather in the positioning and animating of them. When various panels slide in and out, I think they're using something like some CAKeyframeAnimations that activate through an implementation of UIGestureRecognizer.

For vertical scrolling they're using UIScrollView, but for horizontal scrolling, the above is my bet.

Comment: All of the table views are scroll views, of course, so there's no magic needed to get the vertical scrolling. The animations are pretty simple (slide left, slide right); doubt you'd need keyframe animations. But the horizontal scrolling is actually pretty complex. It probably *could* be done with a gesture recognizer, but almost certainly not the stock ones.

Comment: I reckon it could be done with stock UIPanGestureRecognizer and UISwipeGestureRecognizer; they're pretty powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Using my project [FRLayeredNavigationController](https://github.com/weissi/FRLayeredNavigationController) on GitHub you can easily develop UIs very similar to the Twitter iPad app. There's also a [blog post](http://factisresearch.blogspot.de/2012/06/uis-for-hierachical-ipad-apps.html) about it.

If you're interested how it works, just look at the code, it's open sourced ;-). Basically it uses `UIViewController` composition as introduced in iOS 5. It manages multiple "Layers" which are `UIViewController`s you provide. The moving of the layers is triggered by a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and some logic when to move which layer. It looks and feels very nice because of the nice iOS animation support.

`FRLayeredNavigationController`'s API is quite similar to `UINavigationController`, so it's easy to use :-). Samples from my [EuroCopaInfo](https://github.com/weissi/EuroCopaInfo) project, which uses FRLayeredNavigationController:

In file [`StadiumsViewController.m`](https://github.com/weissi/EuroCopaInfo/blob/master/EuroCopaInfo/StadiumsViewController.m):

```
[self.layeredNavigationController pushViewController:wvc inFrontOf:self maximumWidth:YES animated:YES];
```

From [`AppDelegate.m`](https://github.com/weissi/EuroCopaInfo/blob/master/EuroCopaInfo/AppDelegate.m):

```
InfoCategoriesViewController *icvc = [[InfoCategoriesViewController alloc] init];
FRLayeredNavigationController *lnc = [[FRLayeredNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:icvc configuration:^(FRLayeredNavigationItem *item) {
    item.nextItemDistance = 49;
}];
self.window.rootViewController = lnc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Also watch the demo videos/screenshots:

- http://youtu.be/v_tXD_mL05E
- http://youtu.be/q66HX2td_uc
- https://github.com/weissi/FRLayeredNavigationController/raw/master/FRLayeredNavigationControllerScreenshot1.png
- https://github.com/weissi/FRLayeredNavigationController/raw/master/FRLayeredNavigationControllerScreenshot2.png

Answer (score 2):

Here is the good example of getting twitter-like UI for ipad app.

[Check this link](https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView), its really awesome!!!!!

It provides :

- cascade views
- orientation support
- bouncing effect

Comment: Link is dead. Provide alternative or remove the post.

Comment: I found a link to the github page here : https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView

Answer (score 0):

My guess: It's a `UIScrollView` for the horizontal movement, with the `UIView`s behind the main view being animated by hand, depending on where the main view is. The `UIScrollViewDelegate` provides a lot of the methods necessary to animate the background `UIView`s.

Answer (score -1):

Supposedly the developer flattened a navigation controller into slidable panels. Yet no other info is known to my knowledge.

[Original tweet](http://twitter.com/flyosity/status/23259406570)

It kind of makes sense, it's basically just a `UINavigationController` and the way you move up and down the stack changes. Instead of showing just 1 `UIViewController` at a time, now multiple can be shown. I can't really help with the exact implementation though.

Comment: Worth noting: that tweet is just some random guy's conceptual commentary, not any kind of info from the developer.

Comment: Worth noting: it's not some random guy's commentary. Mike Rundle (flyosity) is a pretty well known and respected iOS developer. I'm sure he has had his reasons to tweet that.

Comment: Wasn't impugning his talent. What I meant was, he's an outside observer talking about how the app seems to behave, not someone with any inside knowledge. And, again, he's talking about how the app works conceptually (yes, it's a nav controller laid out edge-to-edge), *not* how that's actually accomplished at a UIKit level (which is what this question is asking). I'd love to read Rundle's speculation on that!

Comment: What Mike Rundle commented on was what the iPad twitter app conceptually do, now how it is actually implemented.